# I can't build C# class library by MonoDevelop on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, monodevelop

When building following simple C# class library,

```
using System;

namespace MyProject
{
    public class MyClass
    {
        public MyClass ()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

I encountered following error message:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.6.4/lib/mono/2.0/Microsoft.Common.targets:
Error: You must specify DestinationFolder or DestinationFiles attribute.
at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Copy.Execute () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Anyone having the same problem?

Somethig I tried:

- This error is solved if I change my
  project file format "MSBuild (Visual
  Studio 2008)" to "MonoDevelop 1.0"
  (Preferences > Load/Save > Project
  file format to use when creating new
  projects)
- There is no problem when building console app project. Only library project is the problem.
- There is no problem on Ubuntu and SUSE

My Environments:

- MonoDevelop 2.2.2
- Mono 2.6.4
- Mac OS X 10.6.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn off following option:

Preferences > Build > Compile projects using MSBuild / XBuild
(this is an experimental feature and may not work for some projects)

I just remembered I turned on that option before by myself :) Thank you.